# Square every value of df column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a df with 2 columns, existing of integer values.

| Apples | Bananas |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 |
| 10 | 4 |

My goal is to grab every column and square the values.
The new df would now look like this:

| Apples | Bananas |
| --- | --- |
| 25 | 4 |
| 100 | 16 |

I began to write a for-loop which does not work like I want to have it.
First I made a list of the columns

Columns = [Apples, Bananas]

Then made the loop:

for column in Columns:
df['squared'] = df[column]**2

This only squares the last column of the df.

Comment: `df = df**2`...

Comment: `df = df**2` would work

Comment: should have known that.. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`DataFrame.pow`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pow.html) method:

```
>>> df = df.pow(2)

   Apples  Bananas
0      25        4
1     100       16
```